# Do PWM Half-Bridge Gate-Drive ICs allow 100% DC?

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, driver, charge-pump, bootstrap

I read in other questions that is not possible to use 100% DC as PWM input for drivers that use a bootstrap/charge pump to shift the gate levels.

I'm talking about common brush DC motor gate drivers, like these:

- [FAN73832](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FAN73832-D.pdf)
- [HIP4081](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/30874.pdf)
- [UCC27710](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc27710.pdf)
- ...

I don't find in the datasheets any requirement for the PWM input signal.
Which parameter should I check to find out if I can reach 100% PWM?

Comment: Make those IC numbers a link to the datasheet, I've done the first, you do the rest. Most datasheets show a block diagram from which you can deduct if a gate driver is suitable for DC signals. It is assumed that from the block diagram you understand how the gate driver works. Gate drivers with a bootstrap circuit generally do not work for DC and need constant switching.

Comment: The ICs you list all use a bootstrap circuit so are unsuitable for DC. But what if you limit the PWM signal to 99%, it will be difficult to notice that 1% difference and could be enough to make the bootstrap circuit work.

Comment: Open the data sheet. Press CTRL-F then type "boot". In the FAN73832 there are 5 occurrences of the word boot or bootstrap.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, sorry, I always put the links but nobody told me it was a good thing. The first time I didn't I've been told to do :) I'm going to add them in a while!

Comment: @Andyaka, it's the other way around: I selected those datasheets *because* they have the "bootstrap" or "charge pump" inside! But if there is a requirement for the PWM input to be < 100% I *must* find it into the datasheet. I've never seen an "implicit" requirement based upon the alleged knowledge of the users.

Comment: The same applies for the suitable PWM frequency range, for example.

Comment: With external circuitry you can get around the bootstrap limitation but some drivers have internal limitation for some 95-99 % max duty cycle. You need to dig into the datasheet.